# Adjusting sizes to screen height

Tags: android, screen-size

I know this question has been asked countless times, and still i cant find the right answer.

I have two devices : Google Pixel 2 and Google Pixel 3 XL.

Physically, Google Pixel 2 is smaller than Google Pixel 3 XL.
Google Pixel 2's density is 2.65, and pixel 3 xl's density is 2.5
they are both XXHDPI.
Obviously the height of the devices visually is different. How come the system keeps taking the wrong values folder ?
How to distinguish on the values folder level between the two devices ?